# Два $$ в цикле foreach в PHP

Tags: php

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    $$key=$value;
}
```

Встретился с такой конструкцией - не могу понять для чего два знака `$$`, не подскажете? Неужто это присваивание `key = value` ? Или что-то другое?

Answer (score 9):

["Переменные переменных"](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.variable.php) это присваивание переменной с именем $key значения $value

если в `$key` было "odessa" а в `$value` "город на Чёрном море" то будет создана переменная

```
$odessa="город на Чёрном море"
```

---

Всю вашу конструкцию можно [записать проще](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.extract.php):

```
extract($_POST);
```

Comment: Не желательно делать `extract` на пользовательский ввод.

Comment: `Внимание
Не используйте extract() на непроверенных данных, таких как пользовательский ввод (например, $_GET, $_FILES).`

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = ['key' => 'value']; $$array['key'] = 'новая';
```

Таким образом мы создали переменную $value со значением "новая", то есть мы взяли для имени новой переменной строковое значени из массива.